# JAVA add a \ before all my /

Tags: java, android

i want to make a JSONObject in java. But when i do this :

```
this.client.put("applicationid", "MOBEGUARD" + '/' + "ANDROID"+ '/'+ android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

but the result is : `"MOBEGUARD\/ANDROID\/4.4.2"`

and i want : `"MOBEGUARD/ANDROID/4.4.2"`

Plz let me know if there is an easy solution to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: whats the difference? its a string value, your server should take it as string

Comment: `MOBEGUARD/ANDROID/4.4.2` is not a valid json value, you are stuck with the `""` if you want this as value

Comment: Lol you can't see here but in the first result i have a \ before /

Comment: Looks like the escapes were being escaped. I edited them back in.

Comment: AFAIK JSON needs to escape slashes hence you get `\/`. If you parse the JSON string those escape characters should be removed. I don't know how Android handles that but in the JSON libraries I uses it was quite simple. Maybe you want to add some more details and code on how you get and print the result.